# Download images automatically

Tags: python, download, urllib

I have written this piece of python code which downloads a number of images from a repository of images and saves them in specified folder. The code looks like this:

```
import urllib.request
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

def store_raw_images():
    neg_images_link = 'http://image-  net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n00464651'
    neg_images_urls =  urllib.request.urlopen(neg_images_link).read().decode()

    if not os.path.exists('neg'):
       os.makedirs('neg')

    pic_num = 1
    for i in neg_images_urls.split('\n'):
        try:
            print(i)
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(i, "neg/{}.jpg".format(pic_num))
            img = cv2.imread("neg/{}.jpg".format(pic_num) + cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            resized_image = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
            cv2.imwrite("neg/{}.jpg".format(pic_num), resized_image)
            pic_num = pic_num + 1
            print(pic_num)

        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

store_raw_images()
```

For some reason the images are replaced and I do NOT see all images. I keep seeing one image `1.jpg` and all the images seem to replaced, though I expect the name of the images to go `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` , ... .

I also see this warning/error but I am not sure if it is relevant to this problem or not.

```
Can't convert 'int' object to str   
http://www.azjeugd.nl/site/modules/xcgal/albums/20082009seizoen/a1/groningen_thuis/IMG_7798.jpg
  HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
  http://www.ga-eagles.nl/images/duels1e0809/gaetel6.jpg
```

Where do you think the problem lies?

Note that I am incrementing the image number:

```
        pic_num = pic_num + 1
```

Comment: What's this `+` in here `cv2.imread("neg/{}.jpg".format(pic_num) + cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`. I don't think that should be there.

Comment: Why not change the file names like this instead?

`"pic "+str(pic_num)+".jpg"`

Comment: I believe the problem was only the '+' sign. Will why do you think `"neg/{}.jpg".format(pic_num)` and `"neg/" + str(pic_num) + ".jpg"` are different? Thanks Rawing for detecting it out !

Comment: The images are being downloaded one after the other neatly. However at some point the program stops with this error: `http://pic20.picturetrail.com/VOL1483/5506924/11018757/343396474.jpg terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr. Process finished with exit code 134`

Is this kind of a memory problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: I noticed the error occurs when querying image No 149. Is there anyway I can reset the downloading from this image number?

Comment: write your images to a list: `neg_images = neg_images_urls.split('\n')` and then start iterating through the list with a defined start position: `for neg_image in range(start_position, len(neg_images): [...]`

Comment: Nice, done and the problem is solved .

Answer (score 1):

You have everything in one `try/except` block. Assuming `cv2.imwrite` fails but all the other lines are executed without any problems, your code will never reach `picnum = picnum + 1`.
Try rearranging your code where you first increase `picnum` and check which lines actually gives you the error.

Comment: To OP: You can avoid mistakes like this if you use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate): `for pic_num, i in enumerate(neg_images_urls.split('\n'), 1):`.

Comment: A few more suggestions, except for the good idea by @Rawing. You use `"neg/{}.jpg".format(pic_num)` three times, use a variable instead, less work if you want to change it later. `split('\n')` can be written as `splitlines()` and will save you the unnecessary empty last field.

Comment: Maxim thanks, I applied your suggestion to the code.